# Is there any pure CSS way to hide only text in the [input=text], not the whole element?

Tags: css

Here is the code:

```css
input[type=text] {display:none}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

It would hide the whole `input` element.

Is there a way to keep the `input` element's out frame UI and just only hide its content without setting its value to `""` by js.

Comment: Why would you want to do this. How will the user know  if they have entered anything and what they have entered?

Comment: May I ask why? `color: transparent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the color transparent.

```css
.value-hidden { color: transparent }
.value-hidden::selection { color:transparent; }
```

```html
<input class="value-hidden" value="the hidden message">
```

Comment: This works, but the user will still be able to see the text by selecting it or copy-pasting it

Comment: works for me. if the user sees the text by selecting, just add a `pointer-events: none`

Comment: @guiseppedeponte I've updated the snippet to hide the selection as well. `pointer-events:none` is tricky, because you won't get javascript events for that element then. `text-indent:-99em` is tricky as well (you noticed yourself) because the text can be arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your input value is not excessively long:

```css
.value-hidden { text-indent: -99em; }
```

```html
<input class="value-hidden" value="the hidden message">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `font-size:0` but you need to make sure to apply a width/height to the input.

```css
input[type=text] {
  font-size:0;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="hello world">
```